# Using linq to find parent with attribute

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have the following XML

```
<Configuration>
    <Organisation Count="2">        
        <ID>1234</ID>    
        <UKPRN Count = "2">
            <NAME>
                <FIRST>abcd</FIRST>
                <LAST>efgh</LAST>   
            </NAME>     
        </UKPRN>            
    </Organisation>
</Configuration>
```

I've tried this

```
var test = root.Elements().Where(p => p.Attribute("Count") != null).Select(p => p.Descendants("FIRST"));
```

but that's the wrong way round. Can't quite get my head around how to get hold of the parent.

How do I use linq to identify the closest parent element with the attribute `Count`, e.g. element `FIRST` should return `UKPRN` and element `ID` should return `Organisation`?

Comment: Perhaps you could start us off with what you have tried so far?

Comment: StackOverflow works this way - you **try** to solve task on your own, and if you have some problems (error or unexpected results), then you give **problem description**, your current **code** and ask people to help you.

Comment: Updated with latest attempt, but still can't get my head round it.

Comment: What do you mean by "e.g. element FIRST should return UKPRN and element ID should return Organisation?"?

Comment: Any reason you don't just use XPath for this?

Comment: For example: `//FIRST/ancestor::*[@Count][position()=1]` returns the closest element to `<FIRST>` that contains a `Count` attribute. See [this example](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/9a197ae35b3c6719640a42139f0608f8).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`Ancestors()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnode.ancestors(v=vs.110).aspx) method to get all the parents and choose the first one that has the attribute you require:

```
var pairs = root.Descendants()
    .Select(e => new 
    {
        Element = e, 
        CountElement = e.Ancestors().FirstOrDefault(a => a.Attribute("Count") != null) 
    });
```